# Generic class parameter not valid for Method?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I've defined a generic type as following:

```
public class RelevanceGroup<T>
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Relevance<T>> Relevances { get; set; } = new List<Relevance<T>> { };

    public RelevanceGroup(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;

    }
    public RelevanceGroup(List<Relevance<T>> relevances, string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Relevances = relevances;
    }

    public bool ChangesHasBeenMade(List<Relevance<T>> newRelevances)
    {
        return !(newRelevances.All(o => this.Relevances.Any(w => w.ItemId == o.ItemId)) && (this.Relevances.All(o => newRelevances.Any(w => w.ItemId == o.ItemId))));
    }
```

My question is regarding the last method:

I get an compile error message in my linq expression saying that "operator == cannot be applied to operands of type T and T". I have to do a foreach loop to make it work. Can i do something to make the method work with the linq expression?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `w.ItemId.Equals(o.ItemId)`

Comment: thanks oerkelens, but does the calling of equals method cause boxing/unboxing?

Comment: If you are worrying about such performance issues, you should look into restraining your `T` to reference types as OfirWinegarten proposes. Only worry about that _if_ it becomes a problem (or if you have good reason to suspect it may become a problem), though! If it does (which it could be if you have large lists), you might want to rethink your strategy to track changes instead.

Answer (score 0):

If `T` is always reference type you can add a constraint for it and it will let you compare with `==`.

```
public class RelevanceGroup<T> where T:class
```

Comment: T is string or Int32

Comment: `int` is a `struct`, then you can't have this constraint. Use `Equals` as others suggested.

Comment: thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the method the compiler doesn't (and cannot) know if T is a type that has the default == operator or it is overloaded. 
You can use the Equals() method instead of ==, like this:

```
    return !(newRelevances.All(o => this.Relevances.Any(w => w.ItemId.Equals( o.ItemId))) && (this.Relevances.All(o => newRelevances.Any(w => w.ItemId.Equals( o.ItemId)))));
```